# EventSystem misinterprets button clicks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I have a problem with clicking on UI buttons. In this video you can see a problem. [VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOpBpYjUbAY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. The problem was in component "Grid Layout Group". I don't know why this component makes my buttons "scary", but it's more good if you place your "tabs" manually.